# Real-time layer 7 (http.request.uri) filtration on freebsd

Tags: firewall, http, freebsd, http-proxy

I have a freebsd 9.0 router with 250-300Mbit/s traffic,
and need to filter small list of pages (http.request.uri).

I do not care about tor, anonymizers, proxy etc. Just prevent direct access from my network to this pages.

How? Only redirect http to squid or any other http-proxy?

I know about tcpdump -ddd and bpf netgraph node. But http is to hard for me.

Comment: +1 Interesant question. So, you currently have a two interfaced FBSD box, currently with NAT-ed (pf?) routing, (therefore don't want use proxy) and want block http requests to exactly defined URIs at some of your interface?

Comment: Yes, ipfw ngnat and routing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want use proxy *(e.g. transparently redirecting all traffic via ipfw rule to proxy - users don't notice anything)* - for the solution you need something what is capable to *deep packet inspection*.

Check the: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipfw-classifyd/ it should do what you want, "layer7 filtering" with ipfw. (or with pf too)

Or, download `pfSense` (freebsd based excellent firewall) and check how to use it. According the docs, (http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Traffic_Shaping_Guide#Layer_7) it is uses `ipfw-classifyd`.

*Ps: only wondering why do you don't using pf instead of ipfw+ngnat)*

Comment: pf can use 1 core. Thanks for ipfw-classifyd going read docs

Comment: Looks like this projects dead.No any activity last 4 years . Status pre-alpha. Divertd socket.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is small, you could just blacklist the IPs in the firewall.

Of course you have to check from time to time, if the pages moved to another site. You could do this with a cron script.

Comment: I cant use ip. Its about big services like youtube.

Comment: youtube sounds like fun, i noticed for example that the google chrome updater sometimes downloads his updates from a youtube domain

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342782/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-ip-addresse-of-youtube-to-block-it-with-windows-firewa  Messing with DNS is also a solution, if your users are unskilled

Comment: yes. dns work for hosts. My problem is that i have list of http url.

Comment: so if you need to filter on http protocol, setting up a transparent proxy with squid is fairly easy. you can find lots of howtos on the net

Comment: Yep, i know about squid, i write about it in Q. But i still hope on another solution

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it without http proxy : Even if you manage to drop TCP packets containing stuff like GET / HTTP/1.1 host: www.youtube.com then, how would you prevent users accessing httpS://www.youtube.com with ssl?